# Line breaks do not work in my JavaScript code

Tags: javascript, jquery, contenteditable

I have the following project which is based on highlighting the `hashtags` that are written within the `contenteditable` box.

The problem is that the code does not allow me to create line breaks.

I need to be able to create new lines and that the cursor position works well.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  function getCaretCharacterOffsetWithin(element) {
    var caretOffset = 0;
    var doc = element.ownerDocument || element.document;
    var win = doc.defaultView || doc.parentWindow;
    var sel;
    if (typeof win.getSelection != "undefined") {
      sel = win.getSelection();
      if (sel.rangeCount > 0) {
        var range = win.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
        var preCaretRange = range.cloneRange();
        preCaretRange.selectNodeContents(element);
        preCaretRange.setEnd(range.endContainer, range.endOffset);
        caretOffset = preCaretRange.toString().length;
      }
    } else if ((sel = doc.selection) && sel.type != "Control") {
      var textRange = sel.createRange();
      var preCaretTextRange = doc.body.createTextRange();
      preCaretTextRange.moveToElementText(element);
      preCaretTextRange.setEndPoint("EndToEnd", textRange);
      caretOffset = preCaretTextRange.text.length;
    }
    return caretOffset;
  }
  function setCaretPosition(element, offset) {
    var range = document.createRange();
    var sel = window.getSelection();
    var currentNode = null;
    var previousNode = null;
    for (var i = 0; i < element.childNodes.length; i++) {
      previousNode = currentNode;
      currentNode = element.childNodes[i];
      while (currentNode.childNodes.length > 0) {
        currentNode = currentNode.childNodes[0];
      }
      if (previousNode != null) {
        offset -= previousNode.length;
      }
      if (offset <= currentNode.length) {
        break;
      }
    }
    if (currentNode != null) {
      range.setStart(currentNode, offset);
      range.collapse(true);
      sel.removeAllRanges();
      sel.addRange(range);
    }
  }
  var textbox = $(".textbox");
  $(document).on("input", textbox, function(event) {
    var position = getCaretCharacterOffsetWithin(textbox.get(0));
    var text = textbox.text();
    text = text.replace(/(^|\s)(#[^\s]+)/ig, "$1<span style=\"color: blue;\">$2</span>");
    textbox.html($.parseHTML(text));
    setCaretPosition(textbox.get(0), position);
  });
});
```

```css
.textbox {
  padding: 6px;
  border: solid 1px #aaa;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="textbox" contenteditable="true"></div>
```

Comment: Could it be this? `text.replace(/(^|\s)(#[^\s]+)/ig,`

Comment: @mplungjan The regular expression works well, I need to be able to include line breaks.